# How to call a function only when an advanced custom field's content is equal to 0?

Tags: php, wordpress

How would I go about calling this function only when an advanced custom field's content is equal to 0

```
 function updateNumbers() {
     global $wpdb;  
     $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb-posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'";  
     $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);  
     $counts = 1440 ;  
     if ($pageposts):  
       foreach ($pageposts as $post):
         setup_postdata($post);  
         $counts++;  
         add_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts, true);  
         update_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts);  
       endforeach;  
     endif;     remove_action ( 'publish_post', 'updateNumbers' ); 
 }     

 add_action ( 'publish_post', 'updateNumbers' );
```

Thanks in advance guys and girls!

++++++EDIT++++++

To clarify, this should describe the function in context:

A div is populated by a wordpress field controlled by the ACF plugin:

```
<?php $post_id = get_field('job-number'); ?>
div class="postID"><?php echo $post_id ?></div>
```

If this value is equal to 0 then I want to run this function:

```
 function updateNumbers() {
     global $wpdb;  
     $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type =
 'post'";  
     $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);  
     $counts = 1440 ;  
     if ($pageposts):  
     foreach ($pageposts as $post):
     setup_postdata($post);  
     $counts++;  
     add_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts, true);  
     update_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts);  
     endforeach;  
     endif; }

 add_action ( 'publish_post', 'updateNumbers' );
```

Comment: Something like `if ($advancedCustomField === 0) { ...`?  Not sure I know what you are asking.

Comment: Exactly what is an "advanced custom field"? Is it a SQL column? Is it a PHP variable?

Comment: Content equal to `0`, or content zero length?

Comment: The advanced custom fields plugin lets you put rich text into custom fields, right?  If that's the case it might not be as straightforward as if ($advancedCustomField === 0), since it could be wrapped in markup.

Comment: @ithcy Advanced Custom Fields are provided by a WordPress plugin to provide more flexibility. It's an attempt to make WordPress more like a CMS.

Comment: Obligatory: Don't use `global`.  At all.  Functions have an argument list (the part that's denoted by `()` in their definitions) that allows you to pass parameters into them.  Use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following seems to be what you're after...

```
<?php
    $key = 'field_name';
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
    if ($meta == '0') {
        updateNumbers();
    }
?>
```